# How do I install PowerToys to many computers in Active Directiry?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-installer, powertoys

We in our company find Microsoft PowerToys a very useful extension to Windows 10. For example the FansyZones power toy alone can take working with Windows to the next level being an awesome hybrid of traditional floating and tiling window management, also adding very handy always-on-top shortcut as a bonus. And it really shines on big screens making using them efficiently very easy.

Now as we are growing 10x after starting with a 5 people team, we feel like adopting Active Directory to manage all the computers the proper centralized way.

Most of the business apps and handy utilities come with an MSI package which can be used to push the app to PCs through AD group policies.

But I couldn't find an MSI package for PowerToys anywhere, they only publish EXE installers alongside the source code at their GitHub page. Anybody could hint me where it is or an alternative way?

Comment: PowerShell used to have a `msi` installer but it has been discontinued.

Comment: If you run: `PowerToysSetup-0.69.1-x64.exe -help` it will show you the help.

Answer (score 1):

See the Microsoft article
[PowerToys Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/grouppolicy)
for details. The following is a summary :

- Download the
  [GroupPolicyObjectsFiles-x.y.z.zip](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases)
  and unzip
- On a domain controller :

  - Copy `PowerToys.admx` to the `PolicyDefinition` folder
  - Copy `PowerToys.adml`to the matching language folder
- The policies under "Administrative Templates/Microsoft PowerToys"
  in both "Computer Configuration" and "User Configuration"
  can force a PowerToys utility to be enabled or disabled for users
  covered by the policy.

Comment: Why the downvote? You said you wanted to use Active Directory.

Comment: It's not me who downvoted. I actually upvoted as I find this useful (I didn't know there is such a policy). Nevertheless I suspect it can only enable/disable PowerToys assuming it's already installed and doesn't install it if it's not.

Comment: @Ivan: My excuses for jumping to conclusions. In case you're right about this policy, see also [Use Group Policy to remotely install software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software). In that case, you can find the PowerToys installation file in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys).